# Download xml from url, parse it and display on page using phonegap on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

Can some one please help me with a sample code (phonegap on WP7) that would fetch a xml from given url, parse the xml and show contents in a list.

I googled a lot but could not find a working solution
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since phonegap is basically rendering HTML files you should look at a way of doing it in HTML and Javascript. Take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249251/consume-data-from-xml-file-in-an-html5-application), it should help you out